# count number of 101 in a string

Tags: c, string, counting

Here is the question: we need to count number of 101 in a string composed of 0s and 1s only. 101 is any subsequence of the string.

> Ex: 10101 has 4 101 in it.

I'm pretty sure that I solved it correctly. For each zero I precalculate number of 1 before it and after it then multiply the answers then add the result to res.

The code is giving me wrong answer for a test case composed of a string of length 1000000.

**I would like to know where is the problem in my code?**

Input for the Test Case: https://he-s3.s3.amazonaws.com/media/hackathon/nitcencode03/problems/p1-6/d434839c-d-input-d4340a6.txt?Signature=IXEy0YlTGPX%2FkjsGoc%2FRxCC8bG8%3D&Expires=1427265583&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJLE6MUHDYS3HN6YQ

Output shoud be **18446708952791232852** but my code is giving **22531786**

Here is my code:

```
char s[1000005];

unsigned long long ans, res, a[1000005];

int main()
{   
    int n;

    scanf("%s", s);
    n = strlen(s);

    a[0] = 0; res = 0;
    for(int i = 1;i <= n;++i)
        a[i] = a[i - 1] + (s[i - 1] == '1');

    for(int i = 1;i <= n;++i)
        if(s[i - 1] == '0') {
            ans = a[n] - a[i];
            ans *= a[i - 1];
            res += ans;
            //if(ans < 0 || res < 0) printf("%lld %lld\n", ans, res);
        }

    printf("%llu\n", res);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1. Your input buffer used by ``scanf()`` might truncate the input. Better read the input string from a file. (or something else goes wrong with using that text input). 2. If you used ``stdint.h`` or ``cstdint`` header file and types like ``uint64_t`` instead of non-portable ``unsigned long long`` you would not be in so much for surprises.

Comment: I tried the same code in C++ using cin >> s where s is a string now and it gave the same result. I don't understand why scanf might truncate the input?

Comment: Where did you come up with the logic to sum the `1`'s and `0`'s to get the answer?  The logic seems flawed, or the posted answer is flawed. There are `434105`-`1`'s, `434684`-`0`'s in a `868789` character string, that according to your code gives `868206` as an answer here, while looking at your posted answer : `18446708952791232852` which is just a little shy of overflowing the unsigned long long MAX. I think your equations are suspect.

Comment: If you look carefully, you'll notice that I said for each zero count number of 1s before it and the number of 1s after it and multiply them then add the answer to the final result. I never said to sum the 1s and 0s to get the answer. Also the final answer will fit perfectly in an unsigned long long. Please read the code carefully.

Comment: @chadi Sometimes it is a environment/console limitation which prevents arbitrary long input. Depends on system.

Comment: @Chadi - agreed, can you drop a link to the final answer. I enjoy a good challenge, but I keep coming up with `13653596984029524` instead of the number you posted. I'd like to see the results. Thanks.

Comment: #user2225104 It might be what you said. Thanks for your response. @david Yes you are right. I think their final answer is wrong as well and maybe they corrected their output. On my machine I also get the same result. Now my code is accepted for all test cases. You can go to www.hackerearth.com and check the problem there. It's called 101 and they have plenty of contests and problems to solve. I kinda like their site.

Answer (score 0):

After having spent some time sussing out various questions surrounding adequate storage types, gcc code/memory models, and promotion/overflow issues, I think I've hit on an approach to this question that I'm satisfied with.

With the size of the data, the default code/memory models are fine. The values stored in the `a` array are well within the `unsigned` type allowing a static declaration of `a[1000000]` to work without causing segmentation fault. (4M storage requirement)

The result value fits within an `unsigned long` (x86_64) or `unsigned long long` (x86). However, there is a subtle issue if the result calculation is not cast to `unsigned long` as neither component of the sum will cause promotion.

With that, I thought I would post this approach to the solution in case anyone else was curious:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define LMAX 868800

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc < 2 ) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Error: insufficient input, usage: %s <filename>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    char s[LMAX] = {0};
    char *p = s;
    unsigned a[LMAX] = {0};
    unsigned long res = 0;
    unsigned n1s = 0;
    unsigned n0s = 0;
    size_t len = 0;
    size_t i = 1;
    FILE *fp = NULL;

    if (!(fp = fopen (argv[1], "r"))) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (!(fgets (s, LMAX - 1, fp))) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: failed to read line from file.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    fclose (fp);

    /* fill a[i] with number of 1's before i in s   */
    while (*p && *p != '\n')
    {
        a[i] = a[i-1] + *p - '0';
        if (*p == '1') n1s += 1; else n0s +=1;
        p++; i++;
    }
    len = p - s;

    p = s;
    i = 1;
    /* for each '0' in s, multiply 1's before i with 1's after i
    and add product to result (i.e. the # of 101's for that 0) */
    while (*p && *p != '\n')
    {
        if (*p == '0')
            res += (unsigned long)a[i - 1] * (a[len] - a[i]);
        p++; i++;
    }

    printf ("\n num 1's  : %u\n num 0's  : %u\n length   : %zu\n results  : %lu\n\n",
            n1s, n0s, len, res);

    return 0;
}
```

**Answer**

```
$ ./bin/num101s d434839c-d-input-d4340a6.txt

 num 1's  : 434105
 num 0's  : 434684
 length   : 868789
 results  : 13653596984029524
```

The data file for this solution is available here as of the date of the solution: [**Input Data**](https://he-s3.s3.amazonaws.com/media/hackathon/nitcencode03/problems/p1-6/d434839c-d-input-d4340a6.txt?Signature=IXEy0YlTGPX%2FkjsGoc%2FRxCC8bG8%3D&Expires=1427265583&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJLE6MUHDYS3HN6YQ)

After dumping to assembler, it appears the following provides a one instruction advantage over the original comparison on Linux/x86_64:

```
    a[i] = a[i-1] + *p - '0';
```

original:

```
    a[i] = a[i-1] + (*p == '1');
```

Comment: Ooh. That's interesting. It's strange when sometimes small details like that affects the behavior of the program or how fast it is. Thanks for the share.

Comment: This was a great question and provided a good challenge and opportunity to revisit a lot of basic that get glossed over most of the time. Yes, I'm always looking for tweaks. For example, I've been using an inline assembly routine to find the most significant bit of numbers that has been the fastest I've seen so far, Yesterday, I stumbled across another in the kernel in __fls.h that is 1000% faster. Doing 100000000 msb calculations is .005 sec compared to .175 sec for the assembly routine. Amazing.Thanks.

Comment: Sure, I put it here [**Efficient Most Significant Bit (MSB) Routine**](http://pastebin.com/dCyM2nsW)